# Not understanding fraction simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not understanding the red colored part and how they are reaching the end result. I spent hours thinking, but in vain. Any  help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)^2 - 2\frac{c}{a}}{\frac{c}{a}},
$$

which seperated is 
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)^2}{\frac{c}{a}} - \frac{2\frac{c}{a}}{\frac{c}{a}}.
$$

This then equals
$$
\frac{b^2}{a^2}\frac{a}{c} - 2\frac c a \frac a c,
$$
cancelling terms we get
$$
\frac {b^2}{ac} - 2.
$$
Now $2=2\frac{ac}{ac}$ so putting this in we get
$$
\frac {b^2}{ac} - \frac{2ac}{ac} = \frac{b^2 -2ac}{ac}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As written in your text

> If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $ax^2 + bx + c$, then $\alpha + \beta = -\frac ba$ and $\alpha\beta = \frac ca$.

Hence (the red colored part)
\begin{align*}
 \frac{(\alpha + \beta)^2 - 2\alpha\beta}{\alpha\beta}
   &= \frac{\left(-\frac ba\right)^2 - 2 \frac ca}{\frac ca}\\
   &= \frac{\frac{b^2}{a^2} - 2\frac{ac}{a^2}}{\frac ca}\\
   &= \frac ac \cdot \frac{b^2 - 2ac}{a^2}\\
   &= \frac{b^2 - 2ac}{ac}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac{\left(-\frac{b}a\right)^2-2\left({c\over a}\right)}{c \over a} & = \frac{a^2}{a^2} \times \frac{\left(-\frac{b}a\right)^2-2\left({c\over a}\right)}{c \over a}\\ & = \frac{a^2\left(-\frac{b}a\right)^2-2a^2\left({c\over a}\right)}{a^2{c \over a}}\\ & = \frac{(-b)^2 - 2ac}{ac} \\ & = \frac{b^2 - 2ac}{ac}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

In solving such problems remember that one has to simplify the expression in terms of what all information he has... In this question all we know about the quadratic is the sum and product of roots... Since sum of roots= -b/a and product of roots=c/a, substitute and get the answer...

{(-b/a)^2 -2(c/a)}/(c/a)

=> {(b^2/a^2) - (2c/a)}/(c/a)

Taking LCM in the numerator and solving

=> {(b^2-2ac)/a^2}/(c/a)

Cancel one a term in the denominator with that of the numerator

=> (b^2-2ac)/ac

Top carry out these operations faster practise and imagine each step as an animation in your mind.. Helps a lot...